# Linux : process state and nettwork request

Tags: linux, linux-networking, linux-kernel

Looking at this post are [are following assertions about linux load and tomcat right ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/949397/are-following-assertions-about-linux-load-and-tomcat-right) ,
I need an information : what is the state of a process waiting for an http request ?

I guess that the process is in sleeping state, then it is remove from the load queue. The point is for a Linux system.

Right ?

I look also at :

- [Linux process state while waiting for a HTTP response](https://serverfault.com/questions/904768/linux-process-state-while-waiting-for-a-http-response)
- [How to know reason of a process going to sleep state and wake it up ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36195/how-to-know-reason-of-a-process-going-to-sleep-state-and-wake-it-up)

Comment: No answer ? Bad news for me.